# rewrite module blocks jquery

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess to redirect my links:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is that this .htaccess doesn't allow jquery to be included in my site even though i have this in the `<head>`

```
<script src="<?php echo WEBROOT;?>views/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

i already tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(views/js/)($|/) - [L]
```

to except the folder where the jquery.js is located. I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/?$
```

but nothing allowed jquery!!

Any solutions please?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` already doesn't redirect existing files no need to add special rules for jquery. Your `src="wrongpath"`  is wrong

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm sure that my `src="NotAWrongPath"`because i could access to the file through ctrl+u in chrome, i even tried to inculde with `src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"` but still doesn't work! By the way, if i disable the .htaccess jquery works fine !!

Comment: Try adding `<base href="/">` to the head of your webpage.

Comment: @MehdiGuelloub prepend https:// to your googleapis.com src and it should work.

Comment: guys still can't find a solution !! i will post my whole code

Answer (score 0):

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this is how I include Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEBROOT;?>js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And this is my index.php page:

```
<?php   
define('ROOT',str_replace('index.php','' ,$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
define('WEBROOT',str_replace('index.php','' ,$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));

require ('core/database.php');
require ('core/controller.php');
require ('core/model.php');
require ('core/view.php');


$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;

if (empty($url)) {
     require ('controllers/home.php');
    $controller = new home();
    return FALSE;
}

$params = explode('/', $url);
$file = 'controllers/'. $params[0] .'.php';
if(is_file($file)){
    require $file;
    $controller = new $params[0]();
    $model = $controller->loadModel($params[0]);

    if(isset($params[1])){
        if (method_exists($params[0], $params[1])) {
            $controller->{$params[1]}();
        }
        else {
            echo '<h1>Method '.$params[1].' of Controller '.$params[0].' Not Found</h1>';
        }
    }
} else {
    /* can't find controller*/
    echo '<h1>Controller Not Found</h1>';
}

?>
```

So Jquery is only working now on home page, I mean in pages like:

[localhost/myProject/controller1/method1](http://#) it doesn't work

Sorry if its a long post but please check it guys